# Lombok is not generating getter and setter

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, lombok

I just tried to send a Maven-based project to another computer and HORROR,
red markers everywhere!!

However, `mvn clean install` is building just fine.

Quickly, I noticed that Lombok is not generating getters and setters for my classes, although the `@Getter` and `@Setter` are being correctly recognised by Eclipse.

Both computers use the same Maven version (3.0.4) but different JDKs (1.6_23 and 1.6_33). They both use Eclipse Indigo 32 bit. Do you have an idea about how to solve the problem?

Comment: For full instructions, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418865/cannot-make-project-lombok-work-on-eclipse-helios/3425327#3425327 . This also incluses how to start Eclipse via a shortcut.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot make Project Lombok work on Eclipse (Helios)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418865/cannot-make-project-lombok-work-on-eclipse-helios)

Comment: I did all the above steps BUT it wasn't working still. I looked at pom.xml again and commented out  <!-- <optional>true</optional> --> which came by default. I later add this <!-- <scope>provided</scope> --> but commented it out as well.

Comment: Why does only Lombok seem to have this problem, seems by design (to get attention)?  Decorators from other annotation jars seem to just work after importing.

Answer (score 253, accepted):

When starting with a fresh eclipse installation you, in fact, need to "install" Lombok before being able to use it.

1. Go where you Lombok jar is (e.g. (e.g. you can find in `~/.m2/repository/org/projectlombok/lombok/1.16.10/lombok-1.16.10.jar`), run it (Example: `java -jar lombok-1.16.10.jar`). A window should appear, browse to your `eclipse.exe` location.
2. Click on install.
3. Launch Eclipse, update project configuration on all projects and voila.

Comment: If even after doing above steps it doesn't work, then EXIT and START eclipse again. Simple File->Restart doesn't work. Explicit EXIT and Start is necessary.

Comment: I believe I did this while eclipse was closed

Comment: If it was closed then fine it work with next start. But if it is already started and Explicit EXIT and start is required.

Comment: Well done @Elidosa --- It's working, but yes need to Exit and start eclipse , only restart does't work

Comment: I also needed to clean the projects to remove compilation errors

Comment: thanks nanosoft!.. I was doing File>restart and it wasn't working..had tried everything

Comment: when I am trying to execute jar getting "Invalid or corrupt jarfile lombok-1.18.2.jar" What to do???

Comment: If any of the above still don't work, ensure the project can be otherwise built/compiled using maven/gradle. Then, delete the project from your workspace, and re-import it, ensuring the project build invocation completes successfully with lombok references in place.

Comment: what in case of Netbeans? Where can I find Netbeans 12.3 location on ubuntu! I tried to /snap, but not working

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/69332138/3637115, it worked for me.

Comment: It works fine, but please make sure you are installing the correct version which is added as dependency for the project. Better, try to installing it after closing your IDE.

Answer (score 126):

- If you use **STS**. You must have Lombok installed in your Eclipse by running lombok-xyz.jar
- Please Try the Following the Steps:

  1. Include pom in Maven .
  2. Exit/Shutdown STS
  3. Find lombok Jar in  ~/.m2/repository/org/projectlombok/lombok/version.x
  4. From Command Prompt/Shell `java -jar lombok-1.x.y.jar`
     [image: Project Lombok Installer]
  5. Start STS

Thats all.

**EDIT**:
I did this and was still showing errors, as mentioned in the comments.
So I updated the project: *right-click on project -> Maven -> Update Project* and the errors disappeared.

Comment: Still I am facing the issue not sure whats wrong is going on ?

Comment: Do you have any error message? 
Can you import the class in your Pojo Files?

Comment: @Prateek In case of not working, please change lombok version.And try again

Comment: I download the lombok.jar manually, ran it and later restarted eclipse and rebuilded projects, it's worked!...

Comment: I had same issue tried everything but didn't work. Then what I did is, I installed fresh and before doing anything I installed Lombok. It worked. Also, make sure that you start with the fresh workspace. It didn't work with the old one.

Answer (score 65):

Note that if you're using IntelliJ, you'll want to install the Lombok plugin (available from IDE settings) and also enable annotation processing.

Comment: Still several would have come to this thread when they were facing the same thing and not knowing if the plugin is needed for the IntelliJ.   thumbs up

Comment: in case of Netbeans? any idea?

Answer (score 21):

Download Lombok Jar, let’s maven do the download on our behalf :

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.18</version>
    </dependency>
```

Now... mvn clean install command on the newly created project to get this jar downloaded in local repository.
Goto the jar location, execute the command prompt, run the command :
java -jar lombok-1.16.18.jar

[image]

click on the “Specify Location” button and locate the eclipse.exe path
LIKE :
[image]

finally install this by clicking the “Install/Update”

Comment: This is the simplest solution i ve found till now. It worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

If you are using maven and Eclipse, must be installed manually.

1. Verify pom

```html
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.10</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
```

2. go to Maven Dependencies

[image]

3. Right click in the library and Run as Java aplication

[image]

4. Especify location IDE, install and close IDE (Eclipse).
   [image]

Comment: I followed all steps you described but with eclipse 2019-12 and lombok 1.18.12, eclipse does not recognize that there is a \@getter or \@setter annotation in my model. Is there even a getter or setter generated by lombok?

Answer (score 10):

If you use STS. You must have Lombok installed in your Eclipse by running lombok-abc.jar

Please Following the Steps:

-Include pom in Maven .
-Exit/Shutdown STS(must)
-Find lombok Jar in ~.m2\repository\org\projectlombok\lombok\1.18.12
-From Command 
[image]

After then
[image]

After then select the STS.exe
[image]

After then click to update/update

[image]

then Quit Installer

Happy Coding

> Blockquote

Comment: it is duplicated answer

Answer (score 8):

If you use eclipse. You must have lombok installed in your Eclipse by running lombok-xyz.jar (e.g. you can find in `~/.m2/repository/org/projectlombok/lombok/1.12.6/lombok-1.12.6.jar`).

As the window of installation opened, you must choose the location of your Eclipse. And let it install lombok inside. You must restart your Eclipse afterwards.

Comment: "Explicitly exit and then start again. ". Normal File-->Restart doesn't work.

Answer (score 7):

These are command line instructions where the above Graphical version is not available or you can not open the Lombok jar file by double clicks, like in Ubuntu.

At the time of writing using Lombok is not straightforward as just adding a dependency in your POM xml file and adding the annotation. These are the next steps:

1) Locate where your Lombok jar file is downloaded by maven; Usually it is in .m2 folder inside your home directory. Then execute the following command.

```
java -jar lombok-1.16.18.jar install <path of where your IDE is installed>
```

example usage:

```
java -jar lombok-x.xx.xx.jar install ~/Downloads/spring-tool-suite-3.9.1.RELEASE-e4.7.1a-linux-gtk-x86_64/sts-bundle/sts-3.9.1.RELEASE/
```

the above command basically makes a configuration update in your IDE `.ini` or `configuration` file something like below:

```
-javaagent:/home/neshant/Downloads/spring-tool-suite-3.9.1.RELEASE-e4.7.1a-linux-gtk-x86_64/sts-bundle/sts-3.9.1.RELEASE/lombok.jar
```

this ensures that the `@Data` or `@Getter` or `@Setter` annotations are understood by the IDE. It is weird that it had to be so complex.

Comment: here I am in year 2020 still finding your post useful. Thanks!

Comment: on point answer, thanks. BTW don't forget to restart sts.

Answer (score 6):

just adding the dependency of Lombok is not enough.
You'll have to install the plugin of Lombok too.

You can get your Lombok jar file in by navigating through (Only if you have added the dependency in any of the POM.)

m2\repository\org\projectlombok\lombok\1.18.12\lombok-1.18.12

Also, if Lombok could not find the IDE, manually specify the .exe of your IDE and click install.

Restart your IDE.

That's it.

If you face any problem,

Below is a beautiful and short video about how to install the plugin of Lombok.

Just to save your time, you can start from 1:40.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5K6NNX-GGDI

If it still doesn't work,

Verify that lombok.jar is there in your sts.ini file (sts config file, present in sts folder.)

-javaagent:lombok.jar

Do an Alt+F5. This will update your maven.

Close your IDE and again start it.

Comment: How come this answer didn't have even a single vote. THis really helped. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 3):

I spent full day, you can do it this way:

1. Add to maven lombok
2. Install eclipse
3. Download lombok
4. Copy to eclipse folder
5. Add to file eclipse.ini next text -javaagent:lombok.jar
6. Active annotation processing in select project (not the parent)
   -> properties
   -> Java compiler
   -> annotation processing
   Select Enable project specific settings Select all Enable checkbox
7. Restart and it should work . test ubuntu 20.04 and eclipse 2021 year

Answer (score 2):

For Sprint STS - Place the lombok.jar file in the eclipse/sts exe folder and add the following entry to the STS.ini.

```
-javaagent:lombok.jar
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution for Eclipse IDE:

**1. Maven dependency in pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

**2. Go to Maven dependency jar >> Right click >> Run As >> Java Application**

**3. select ***Socket Server*** and Click OK**

```
ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SimpleSSLSocketServer
ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SimpleSocketServer
```

**4. Show message on console like:**

Wrong number of arguments.
Usage: java ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SimpleSocketServer port configFile

Answer (score 1):

When using lombok on a fresh installation of Eclipse or STS, you have to:

1. Install the lombok jar which you can get at https://projectlombok.org/download. Run the jar (as Administrator if using windows) and specify the path to your Eclipse/STS installation.
2. Restart your IDE (Eclipse or STS)
3. Give some time for eclipse to generate the class files for lombok (Might take a up to 4 mins in some cases)

Answer (score 1):

For Spring ToolSuite 4 on Mac, they renamed the ini to SpringToolSuite4.ini.

You can either rename or copy it to STS.ini to be recognized by lombok. Then copy it back to the original name to be read by the IDE. (Haven't tried if symbolic links work though.)

Answer (score 1):

Download Lombok Jar File https://projectlombok.org/downloads/lombok.jar

Add maven dependency:

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>1.16.18</version>
   </dependency>
```

Start Lombok Installation `java -jar lombok-1.16.18.jar`

find complete example in this link:
  https://howtodoinjava.com/automation/lombok-eclipse-installation-examples/

Answer (score 1):

I am using Red hat Jboss developer studio. I solved this issue by:

1. The project has `lombok` dependency. First look into your `.m2`
   repository and find the `lombok` jar
2. Double click on the jar, you will see installer there specify the path for IDE like `C:\Users\xxx\devstudio\studio\devstudio.exe`
3. Restart the IDE and update the maven project the error will go

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please try to write your answers more readable, by using correct lists and `markdown language like this`.

Answer (score 1):

1) Run the command `java -jar lombok-1.16.10.jar`. This needs to be run from the directory of your lombok.jar file.

2) Add the location manually by selecting the **eclipse.ini** file(Installed eclipse directory). Through “**Specify location**”

**Note :** Don't add the **eclipse.exe** because it will make the eclipse editor corrupt.

[How to add the eclipse.ini file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCC2y.png)

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this issue, for my case, it's because I upgrade my IntelliJ IDEA without upgrading the Lombok plugin. So they are incompatible.

Comment: Just upgrade the Lombok Plugin in Intellij Idea and restart the IDE

Answer (score 1):

What I had to do was to install `lombok` in the eclipse installation directory.

Download the `lombok.jar` from [here](https://projectlombok.org/downloads/lombok.jar) and then install it using the following command:

```
java -jar lombok.jar
```

After that make sure that the `lombok.jar` is added in your build path. But make sure you don't add it twice by adding once through `maven` or `gradle` and once again in eclipse path.

After that `clean` and `build` the project again and see all the errors go away.

Answer (score 1):

Intellij User, make sure you have 3 things,

1. Lombok dependency

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.8</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

2. IntelliJ plugin for Lombok
3. Lombok annotation, like `@Getter @Setter` (make sure it is coming from lombok and not from somewhere else)

and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Seem the answers above are OK in some cases but my case not work well somehow.

So, here what I did (that worked for me):

1. I use Spring Suit 4 (SpringToolSuite4.exe)
2. Projects must be maven-project
3. I direct install lombok the version I put in pom.xml (1.18.12) not working
4. I changed to install lombok the latest version via Market Place, use site: `https://projectlombok.org/p2`, the version is 1.18.22
5. I see now in my `SpringToolSuite4.ini`, this line: `-javaagent:D:\xxx\eclipse\sts-4.13.0.RELEASE\plugins\org.projectlombok.agent_1.18.22/lombok.jar`
6. Re-open my STS and press: `ALT+F5` (to open your maven projects), click OK and wait all projects to be built

And they are working.

**Discussion**

It might be above all solutions are working but can because of the version as we always thought, we need to use the same version as in our pom.xml but it could also work with the latest one (correct me if anyone have comment).

Point 2. maven projects, I did since beginning with other above solutions but still got error; somehow we have to make sure that.

**One more remark**: *whenever you don't see a line of message in About Spring Tool (or About Eclipse), meant that your lombok installation not correct*, may try my above solution again.

Hope this discussion helps others.

Answer (score 1):

open cdm from your local system and follow the step below till lombok folder

Step 1 : open cm from your local system
Step 2 : cd .m2\repository\org\projectlombok\lombok\1.18.26(till version which present in your system) and do step 3
Step 3: java -jar lombok-1.18.26.jar
Then after one window will appear like below image-1 and wait till full scan then click install/update.

[image: image-1]

Step 4: Restart your STS or Eclipse then start work enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

In mac os lombok will not be able to find eclipse location.
please click on specify location and go to the eclipse installed folder
you can find the eclipse.ini file select that

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are already many answer to this question. I'll add to the already given answer.

For Spring STS, if after following the correct way and installing and you get install successful and still it is not working. Please follow below steps.

1. Open .ini file. and update the javaagent value like this. Also make sure you have lombok.jar in the same folder.

   **-javaagent:lombok.jar**
2. Now restart the STS and then right click on the project.
3. Maven -> Update Project
4. Check force Update of snapshot/releases.
5. click on OK.

It will take some time and it will resolve all lombok errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using IntelliJ IDEA

1.Install the Lombok plugin
2.Enable annotation processing
Go to File > Settings (or IntelliJ IDEA > Preferences on macOS).
In the settings dialog, navigate to Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Annotation Processors.
Check the box for "Enable annotation processing.

Answer (score 0):

Add below line in SpringToolSuite4.config file at last
**-javaagent:lombok.jar**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Remove @Getter from private static field.

https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1493

Answer (score -1):

If you are using maven , Go to maven dependencies in your project structure then run lombok jar as java project it will install it then exit and start eclipse