# Can't compile project with Lombok in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, lombok

*I'm [asking and answering my own question](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), but i'm not assuming i have the best answer. If you have a better one, please post it!*

Related Questions:

- [Lombok is not generating getter and setter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11803948/lombok-is-not-generating-getter-and-setter)
- [Can't compile project when I'm using Lombok under IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9424364/cant-compile-project-when-im-using-lombok-under-intellij-idea)

Here are the symptoms:

1. I have this compilation [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSVrU.png): "Cannot find symbol method getName()" when I try to run the code or when I do "mvn clean install".
2. If I go to

> Refactor -> Lombok or Delombok

all annotations are marked as ["readonly"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xb9Y.png)

3. If I go in any class with Lombok annotations none of them are marked with red underline.

As IDE I use IntelliJ and the project was generated with springinitializr.

I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: hover over the name in Person class is there any warning or yellow line such as The *value of the field Person.name is not used*

Comment: Could you please share  error. @Data will generate getter/setter equals and hashcode..Other annotations you can remove.

Comment: How do you run the service? via IDE or command line? If IDE which IDE you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps:

1. I updated the lombok plugin version:

> File -> Settings -> Plugins -> Updates

2. Restart IDE.
3. Download the lombok [JAR](https://projectlombok.org/download)
4. Run this command:

`mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.projectlombok -DartifactId=lombok -Dversion=1.1.18 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file`

Answer (score 3):

**For IntelliJ:**

1) Enable Annotation Processing

File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Annotation Processors -> Click the checkbox Enable Annotation Processor

2) Install/Update Lombok Plugin (see this)

File -> Settings -> Plugins -> Search for Lombok Plugin -> Update or Install

Comment: I tried both. I updated lombok and it's still not working.

Answer (score 1):

add this in dependencies in build.gradle

```
annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.6"
```