# Lombok not recognizing getters and setters

Tags: java, spring-boot, lombok, spring-tool-suite

I am trying to set up lombok in my sts.

So far I have done these steps:
I downloaded the lambok jar file.
I ran the file and specified the path for sts.exe and then clicked on install.
I have added the required dependencies in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
<artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
<optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

I have also edited my sts.ini file. After installation of lambok.jar following line was already there at the end pf the file

```
-javaagent:E:\JAVA SOFTWARES\spring-tool-suite-3.9.8.RELEASE-e4.11.0-win32-x86_64\sts-bundle\sts- 
 3.9.8.RELEASE\lombok.jar
```

so I moved it next to

```
-vmargs
```

Then, I cleaned my project. I have also updated my project. Closed sts and then ran my application again. But it is still not recognizing the getters in my file. It produces the following error.

```
  The method getFirstname() is undefined for the type Student
```

Student.java:

```
package com.crud.msstudent.models;

 import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.experimental.Accessors;

@Getter
@Setter
@Accessors(chain=true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@NotEmpty(message = "First name is required")
private String firstname;

@NotEmpty(message = "Last name is required")
private String lastname;

@Column(nullable = true, name = "email")
private String email;

}
```

The error is being shown in my StudentController.java file. Following is some of the code:

```
 @PutMapping(value="/students/{id}")
public Student updateStudent(@PathVariable("id") @Min(1) int id, @Valid 
@RequestBody Student newstd) {
    Student stdu = studentservice.findById(id)
                                 .orElseThrow(()->new 
  StudentNotFoundException("Student with "+id+" is Not Found!"));
    stdu.setFirstname(newstd.getFirstname());
    stdu.setLastname(newstd.getLastname());
    stdu.setEmail(newstd.getEmail());
    return studentservice.save(stdu); 
}           
@DeleteMapping(value="/students/{id}")
public String deleteStudent(@PathVariable("id") @Min(1) int id) {
    Student std = studentservice.findById(id)
                                 .orElseThrow(()->new 
StudentNotFoundException("Student with "+id+" is Not Found!"));
    studentservice.deleteById(std.getId());
    return "Student with ID :"+id+" is deleted";            
}
```

Please tell me what am I missing?

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: show `Student` class

Comment: have you add @ getter @ setter or @ data annotation to your class?

Comment: @AshishKarn I am using STS.

Comment: @user7294900 Sure Please check my updated question

Comment: @Habil yes. Please check my updated question

Comment: Everything seems correct. Do once fresh installation using this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11803948/lombok-is-not-generating-getter-and-setter) and verify at location ~/.m2/repository/org/projectlombok/lombok/

Comment: @Habil what do you meean?

Comment: @AshishKarn I have already done everything in this link but unfortunately the problem is still there. and yes It is there at ~/.m2/repository/org/projectlombok/lombok/

Comment: annotation processing must be enabled

Comment: @Bohemian How can I enable annotation processing in STS? I cant find such option here.

Comment: Does `mvnw.cmd clean compile` command succeed?

Comment: where should I run this coomand? mvnw.cmd clean compile

Comment: Follow the Lombok installation instructions [here](https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-ide)

Comment: Please post your entire eclipse.ini file.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using STS you might be missing the plugin required for it. For further details please refer to the Lombok [site](https://projectlombok.org/setup/eclipse) on how to install it.

Comment: I have the required plugin as mentioned and have already specified the path of sts.exe as well.

Answer (score 0):

If `mvnw.cmd clean compile` command works normally, try project reloading.

Right click your project folder in Package Explorer > Maven > Update Project

[image]

Answer (score 0):

are you using Eclipse IDE? in some case, you have to update the project explicitly in eclipse.

better to go without using lombok

```
public class Student implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@NotEmpty(message = "First name is required")
private String firstname;

@NotEmpty(message = "Last name is required")
private String lastname;

@Column(nullable = true, name = "email")
private String email;

public Student()
 {
  }

 public Student(int id,String firstname,String lastname,String email)
 {
          this.id=id;
          this.firstname=firstname;
          this.lastname=lastname;
          this.email=email
   
 }



public int getId()
    {
    return id;
    }
   public void setId(int id)
   {
       this.id=id;
   }

   public String getFirstname()
    {
    return firstname;
    }
   public void setFirstname(String firstname)
   {
       this.firstname=firstname;
   }

   public String getLastname()
    {
    return lastname;
    }
   public void setLastname(String lastname)
   {
       this.lastname=lastname;
   }

public String getEmail()
    {
    return email;
    }
   public void setEmail(String email)
   {
       this.email=email;
   }
```

Comment: I am using STS.

Comment: create explicit getters & setters then it will be fine

Answer (score 0):

Does this help [(source)](https://projectlombok.org/setup/maven):

To include `lombok` as a 'provided' dependency, add it to your  block like so:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.12</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

JDK9+ with module-info.java
The configuration of the compiler plug-in should contain the following:

```
<annotationProcessorPaths>
    <path>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.12</version>
    </path>
</annotationProcessorPaths>
```