# Why lombok do not create the setters and getters?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, lombok

I am new to Spring Boot framework and lombok.

I defined my entity like that:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Student implements Serializable{
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String firstName;    
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
}
```

I also create a controller where I add the following:

```
 @PostMapping(path="/add") // Map ONLY POST Requests
      public @ResponseBody String addNewUser (@RequestParam String name
          , @RequestParam String email) {
        // @ResponseBody means the returned String is the response, not a view name
        // @RequestParam means it is a parameter from the GET or POST request

    Student st = new Student();
    st.setFirstName(name);
    st.setEmail(email);
    //studentservice.save(st);
    return "Saved";
  }
```

I dont know why I have a red line under setFirstName. They ask me to create this function in the student class.

I am using eclipse.

Comment: are you having lombok plugin for eclipse?

Comment: Question may be duplicate of:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11803948/lombok-is-not-generating-getter-and-setter

Comment: @AnkitSharma I just added the depdency whe I configured the Spring Boot

Comment: you also need plugin in eclipse https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-ide

Answer (score 0):

please follow the steps as below:

check pom.xml for lombok dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.20</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Now you can check your IDE,
I hope, it helps!

Comment: When I configured Spring Boot projet I added lombok. So in my Pom.xml I have the following: <dependency>
   <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
   <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
   <optional>true</optional>
  </dependency>