# Cannot access javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass Spring Boot 3

Tags: spring, jpa, jakarta-migration, mappedsuperclass, spring-boot-3

I've migrated my project from Spring Boot 2 to Spring Boot 3 and I've been getting this error:

```
[1;31mERROR[m] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[1;34mINFO[m] -------------------------------------------------------------
[1;31mERROR[m] cannot access javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass
  class file for javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass not found
[1;31mERROR[m] /F:/nsc/src/main/java/com/fluentgrid/nsc/service/NewRegistrationsTService.java:[1278,88] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method setRecordStatus(java.lang.Integer)
  location: variable miscellaneousFeeDetails of type com.fluentgrid.nsc.model.MiscellaneousFeeDetails
[1;31mERROR[m] /F:/nsc/src/main/java/com/fluentgrid/nsc/service/NewRegistrationsTService.java:[1279,88] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method setUpdatedBy(java.lang.String)
  location: variable miscellaneousFeeDetails of type com.fluentgrid.nsc.model.MiscellaneousFeeDetails
[1;31mERROR[m] /F:/nsc/src/main/java/com/fluentgrid/nsc/service/NewRegistrationsTService.java:[1280,88] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method setUpdateDate(java.util.Date)
  location: variable miscellaneousFeeDetails of type com.fluentgrid.nsc.model.MiscellaneousFeeDetails
```

I've got 2 classes that use MappedSuperclass and I changed their imports to `jakarta`:

[image: Search]

Any solution to resolve this?

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.fluentgrid</groupId>
<artifactId>fgcis-ms</artifactId>
<version>2.0.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2</version>
</parent>

<repositories>
    
    <repository>
        <id>maven.restlet.org</id>
        <name>maven.restlet.org</name>
        <url>http://maven.restlet.org</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>


<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <apache-chemistry-opemcmis.version>0.12.0</apache-chemistry-opemcmis.version>
    <apache-camel-restlet-starter.version>2.23.0</apache-camel-restlet-starter.version>
    <keycloak.version>9.0.2</keycloak.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.xml.ws-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Commons -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Needed for Async Logging with Log4j 2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lmax</groupId>
        <artifactId>disruptor</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Specs -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Alfresco -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.chemistry.opencmis</groupId>
        <artifactId>chemistry-opencmis-osgi-client</artifactId>
        <version>${apache-chemistry-opemcmis.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.xml.stream</groupId>
                <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-restlet-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${apache-camel-restlet-starter.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20200518</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
        <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.24</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
        <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>stax</groupId>
                <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.net.httpserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>http</artifactId>
        <version>20070405</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>6.6.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.xml.stream</groupId>
                <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>stax</groupId>
                <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.14</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <!-- spring boot cache dependency. -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- ehcache dependency. -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.8</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-tools-common</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-security</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.directwebremoting</groupId>
        <artifactId>dwr</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2-RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.jws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.jws-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak.bom</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
                <!--<compilerArguments>
                    <Xmaxerrs>1000</Xmaxerrs>
                </compilerArguments>-->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openrewrite.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>rewrite-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <activeRecipes>
                    <recipe>org.openrewrite.java.spring.boot3.UpgradeSpringBoot_3_1</recipe>
                </activeRecipes>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.openrewrite.recipe</groupId>
                    <artifactId>rewrite-spring</artifactId>
                    <version>5.0.8</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

EDIT:

No javax import for MappedSuperclass:
[image: No javax import]

Comment: Is the `NewRegistrationsTService` class yours? The problem is this

Comment: yeah this is my class, but i'm also facing a lombok issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

entity class takes from jakarta.* but superclass takes from javax.*

do it same)

Answer (score 0):

If you will add `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` dependency that start from `3.x` version:

Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>version(>3.x)</version>
</dependency>
```

Gradle:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:version:(>3.x)'
```

And in entity class:

```
@MappedSuperclass
```

This annotation will be imported from:

`import jakarta.persistence.MappedSuperclass;`

Because started from `spring-boot` version > 3.x all `javax.` packages was changed to `jakarta.`

About imports `javax.` that you use, some imports remain like :

```
 javax.sql. 
 javax.net.
 javax.xml.
```

But `javax.mail` to `jakarta.mail`

Comment: I am using the 3.1.2 version for spring-boot-starter-data-jpa which is being managed by spring-boot-starter-parent and the error still shows up.

Comment: in this case be sure that you remove all `javax` dependency from the project

Comment: also try to rebuild it

Comment: Did that, but unfortunately this error did not get resolved.

Comment: Can you also provide your pom.xml/build.gradle file ? just update the question

Comment: Yeah I've added the pomxml

Comment: just execute this comand  on project `mvn clean install`

Comment: I get these errors when i do maven clean install

Comment: can you share the error ? also update the question

Comment: The error that I've mentioned in the question is the error I'm getting when I do mvn clean install

Comment: yep, i got it, i think you should clean `.m2` repository also, and  import dependency again

Comment: also, have you tried to invalidate cache on you code editor and restart ? because i think it is a code editor problem

Comment: I did do this and my .m2 repository doesn't import the javax.persistence folder. Idk why this error keeps popping up.

Comment: you can check with `mvn dependency:tree` if it is present, also recheck the imports in your code, maybe you miss something to remove

Comment: find in all project files `javax.` imports and replace it with `jakarta.` i am sure you miss something

Comment: I've got some imports of `javax` in my project, and I couldn't find any `jakarta` versions for these imports. Can you please check. I updated my question.

Comment: of course, i will check also i will let you know

Comment: got something for this?

Comment: i will let yo know.

Comment: @LohitAkshay i added information about it

Comment: hey how do i find this?

Comment: oh thanks for the input, I've changed the to jakarta.mail but unfortunately I still get the errors.

Comment: can you update the question with full maven error trace after `mvn clean install` ?

Comment: also be sure that you have removed from code `import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass`

Comment: I updated my question and when I migrated my project, I am getting lombok getters and setters errors aswell. I've put up a question for that aswell : [Lombok not generating getters and setters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76991012/lombok-is-not-generating-getter-and-setter-methods). After going through many solutions I thought maybe the MappedSuperclass error breaks lombok's annotation processor. Lombok works with Spring Boot 2.7 btw. I'm using the same lombok version for both these Spring Boot versions(which is the latest one).

Comment: i will answer to both questions, give me some time

Comment: can you update the lombok version to latest one `1.18.28` ? and retry

Comment: and also [lombok-is-not-generating-getter-and-sette](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11803948/lombok-is-not-generating-getter-and-setter)

Comment: I already updated lombok version to `1.18.28` , I just used `1.18.24` to check if it solves the issue, but neither of them do.

Comment: By using this [lombok-is-not-generating-getter-and-setter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11803948/lombok-is-not-generating-getter-and-setter) , I can confirm it's installation by going to `Help -> About STS -> checking for lombok version installed` and it shows `1.18.28`.

Comment: remove all dependency with lombok from the project and be sure that you are using a version from `lombok 1.18.22` because it is possible to use with `jdk17 `. I suggest to change the lombok management from spring and import it as separate dependency in the `pom..xml` file [lombok/1.18.28](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok/1.18.28) and leave it with  ` <scope>provided</scope>`

Comment: Please see this : [Lombok jar](https://ibb.co/XCvWY14) as you can see, I am using a separate dependency for lombok, and it is accessible only through the lombok dependency.

Comment: idk, i think if you share the github link to the project i can fix it, because without seeing the code i cant say somethig

Comment: Hey I've solved this issue btw, we know that everything changed to jakarta from javax (including javax.MappedSuperClass) but for some weird reason, MappedSuperClass when imported from javax, it works even for Spring Boot 3. When I try to import it from jakarta, it throws an error, so I've changed it to javax and the project got built. You can update answer if you want and I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: Hi, i am really happy for you.