# Lombok is not generating getter and setter in eclipse ide after maven install

Tags: spring, lombok

in my spring boot project i am using lombok dependency , maven install working fine , but lombok not genrating getter and setter in eclipse.

i tried to do maven install the lombok dependency are present under maven dependency also did maven update , but still not working . Can anyone help on this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lombok is not generating getter and setter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11803948/lombok-is-not-generating-getter-and-setter)