# Unable to resolve type for lombok log4j and slf4j in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, lombok

I downloaded and installed Lombok project (1.16.16) in eclipse maven project. I also see a new javaagent line added to my eclipse.ini file. I am able to use @Getter and @Setter annotations, however when I try to add @Log4j or @Slf4j annotation it shows red squiggly immediately. I restarted eclipse, cleaned the project but no help. 
Error message says "org.apache.log4j.Logger cannot be resolved to a type". I don't understand why it is asking me to import Apache jar when I am using lombok.

[image]

I also tried changing maven repo assuming if there would be some conflicting libraries which might be causing this, but it doesn't seem to work either.

Am I missing anything? I think all possible solutions I could find online.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Building with Lombok's @Slf4j and Eclipse: Cannot find symbol log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16627751/building-with-lomboks-slf4j-and-eclipse-cannot-find-symbol-log)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logging library still needs to be a dependency of your project. Add it to your `pom.xml`.

Comment: Yes. After adding log4j jar it worked. So lombok seems to be wrapper on top of these logging lib.

Comment: @VrushankDoshi Yes, Lombok is just generating the code to declare the `Logger` for you.