# How to actually make lombok annotations work for getters and setter

Tags: java, eclipse, lombok

I am trying to use lombok getters and setters annotations.
As far as I know the annotated code is generated at runtime and not compile time so how can take the help of autogenerated getters and setters for writing code?

for example I have a class like this

```
@lombok.Getters
@lombok.Setters
public class MyLombokTesting {

private String userName;

}
```

but what is the use of such annotations if these are not generated while writing code...

Now I want to do something like this

```
MyLombokTesting myLombokTesting = new MyLombokTesting();
String username = myLombokTesting.getUserName();
or myLombokTesting.setUserName("some username");
```

but I can't do any of these since there are no setters and getters generated for me in eclipse while writing code..

Obviously I can have a one argument constructor to set the username but what about getter?

Comment: Have you tried the Eclipse plugin? Also, you misspelled Lombok everywhere.

Comment: It is used for accessing properties using Interospection, for example what is done with most MVC frameworks in binding request parameters to properties, or what is done with Hibernate and ....

Comment: @user well you'll have to tell us what "lambok" is then because nothing turns up on Google. Despite your denials the prior is strongly in favor of you using the misspelled Lombok library.

Answer (score 12):

First of all, Lombok does run compile time to change the generated class file on the fly.

Possibly, lombok is not correctly installed in your Eclipse. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418865/cannot-make-project-lombok-work-on-eclipse-helios/3425327#3425327) on lombok installation problems in Eclipse.

Furthermore, the runtime processing of annotations is not the only use for them. Java 5 already shipped with [apt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/apt/GettingStarted.html), the Annotation Processing Tool and since java 6 annotations can be processed by the standard compiler (javac). Annotations can generate class files, source files or other resource files.

Disclosure: I am one of the [Project Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/) developers

Comment: @Roel_Spilker Is there a way to configure Lombok to put Hibernate annotations on Getters instead of properties?

Comment: Why Setter and Getter is having meta-annotation `@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.TYPE})` but cannot be applied on annotations?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you Restart Eclipse/Intellij or Any IDE that you are working in after adding Lombok jars and plugins.

Answer (score 1):

I use Eclipse IDE. I have to install lombok in my computer before adding lombok library in pom.xml

**Step 1:**
- Download lombok at https://projectlombok.org/download
- Run command **java -jar** 
[image]
- Restart your IDE
- Finish

**Step 2:**
- Add lombok to pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.8</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

- call getter / setter in your code
  [image]