# how to configure lombok in eclipse luna

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, lombok

I configure lombok in eclipse Luna with Maven. Annotation is added properly, but no getter and setter are generated.

eclipse.ini

```
`-vm E:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\bin`
`-vmargs`
`-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7`
`-javaagent:F:\Tools\Java Lib\Lombok\lombok.jar`
`-Xbootclasspath/a:F:\Tools\Java Lib\Lombok\lombok.jar`
`-Xms40m`
`-Xmx512m`
```

Comment: The link http://jnb.ociweb.com/jnb/jnbJan2010.html at lombok website is nice tutorial

Comment: this link https://nawaman.net/blog/2017-11-05 is good, it can helps you

Answer (score 65):

Disclosure: I am one of the lombok developers. I might be biased :-)

I strongly suggest installing Lombok via executing the lombok jar: `java -jar lombok.jar` The spaces in the path might be a problem.

Also, you'll need to use lombok version 1.14.8 (or higher) to have Luna support.

Please check in the About Eclipse screen if lombok is installed correctly.

See also [Cannot make Project Lombok work on Eclipse (Helios)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418865/cannot-make-project-lombok-work-on-eclipse-helios/3425327#3425327)

Comment: Lombok 1.14.4 is working fine at Eclipse Luna and Eclipse Mars. But it was not working at Eclipse Kepler.

Comment: Also make sure your Eclipse is closed or close and open it again after installing Lombok. Restart doesn't work this way.

Comment: For Mac users, when the Lombok GUI installer asks for an IDE location because it couldn't fine one, browse and point it to eclipse.ini inside your .app . Quit eclipse and restart.

Comment: Hello @Roel Spilker.

How about Eclipse Mars 2?
When I tried it there it crashes my EclipseMars2.

Comment: Mars should be fine. what version of lombok are you using? What is the exact problem?

Comment: Also note that you cannot change the name of the eclipse executable (eclipse.exe), because eclipse.ini won't be loaded and default configuration will be used.

Comment: For me I execute java -jar lombok.jar and I did force update of my project for clean 
 errors of my project

Comment: What does `java -jar lombok.jar` exactly do? Is there a procedure of doing it manually? I escaped from Windows to Linux and one of the reasons is my dislike for installers.

Answer (score 46):

Here is the complete steps to be followed, you wont see any issues.

**1. Download Lombok Jar File -** 
Its better to have a Maven/Gradle dependency in your application. The maven depency can be found here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok

**2. Start Lombok Installation -**
Once the jar downloaded in Local repository, goto the jar location from command prompt and run the following command `java -jar lombok-1.16.18.jar` and we should be greeted by Lombok installation window provided by lombok like this.

**3. Give Lombok Install Path -** Now click on the `“Specify Location”` button and locate the `eclipse.exe/STS.exe` path under eclipse installation folder like this.

[image]

**4. Finish Lombok Installation -** Now we need to finally install this by clicking the **“Install/Update”** button and we should finished installing lombok in eclipse and we are ready to use its hidden power. Final screen will look like,

[image]

**5. Please make sure to add below entry into the `STS.ini` file, if its not already there.**

```
-vmargs -javaagent:lombok.jar
```

**Note**: After doing all this if this doesn't worked then make sure to change the workspace and build the code again. It will work.

Answer (score 21):

For Integrattion with ECLIPSE LUNA in Windows 7 please foollow the below steps:

- Download the jar -> lombok-1.14.6.jar.
- Using command prompt go to java installed directory and type

  ```
  java -jar ${your_jar_path}\lombok-1.14.6.jar.
  ```

  Here ${your_jar_path} is your lombok-1.14.6.jar jar store directory.
- After this it will prompt for Eclipse already installed in your system and you need to select where you want to integrate.
- After this you need to open eclipse.ini file and make entry below

  ```
  -vmargs
  ```

  as

  ```
  -Xbootclasspath/a:lombok.jar
  -javaagent:lombok.jar
  ```
- Start your eclipse now and create a Maven project and make entry in pom.xml as mentioned below:

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>1.14.6</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  ```

After this your are ready to write your code and check it.
Without @DATA annotation it looks like:
[image]
With @DATA annotation it looks like:
[image]

An example i ran the command

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75>java -jar
>   C:\Users\Shareef-VM.m2\repository\o
>   rg\projectlombok\lombok\1.14.8\lombok-1.14.8.jar

Answer (score 9):

It began to work only after

**eclipse -clean**.

And I have to launch it so each time. **-clean** in eclipse.ini doesn't help.

Other solutions weren't helpful too.

Comment: `eclipse --clean` was needed only once

Comment: @user1648825 best answer. After installing using "java -jar" just need to perform a maven clean and the magic happens (I´m using jdk8 and STS 3.6.4 and 3.8.2 on windows 7)

Comment: @ That was exactly what helped me. I had already tried with "eclipse restart" and even closing and running eclipse again. But they didn't help. Just when I cleaned the project once, it worked. Thanks :)

Comment: pretty same way is, once eclipse is running, clean the project

Answer (score 7):

if you're on windows, make sure you 'unblock' the lombok.jar before you install it.
if you don't do this, it will install but it wont work.

Comment: What does it mean to 'unblock' the jar?

Comment: @NateGlenn Check in properties - Windows blocks files downloaded from the net. Unblock the file in its properties.

Answer (score 6):

After two weeks of searching and trying, the following instructions works in

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)
Build id: 20180405-1200

1. Copy Lombok.jar to installation directory my case (/opt/eclipse-spring/)
2. Modify eclipse.ini 
   openFile 
   --launcher.appendVmargs

as follows:

```
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-javaagent:/opt/eclipse-spring/lombok.jar
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
```

......

In build.gradle dependencies, add lombok.jar from file as follows

compileOnly files('/opt/eclipse-spring/lombok.jar')

And yippee, I have a great day coding with lombok.

Answer (score 5):

**Step 1:** Create a maven project in Eclipse and add the below dependency in the pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.16.18</version>
</dependency>
```

**Step 2:** Run As --> Configuraitons --> Goto Arguments --> give arguments like below
maven -clean install

[image]

**Step 3:** Run As --> maven clean

Once you do the maven clean you see Build Success and lombok jar file in the maven Dependencies

[image]

**Step 4:** Goto the jar location as shown in the below screen shot.

[image]

**Step 5:** Give command as shown like below after reaching in the .m2 folder

[image]

**Step 6:** Locate where is your eclipse folder once you this window.Once you see Install Successfull message click on **Quit Installer** option at the bottom.

[image]

**Step 7 :** We have finished installing the lombok.jar successfully .Now restart your Eclipse IDE and Start below Sample Code to check whether the data is coming or not in the getters and setters.

Step 8: Open Eclipse and create simple Java Maven project and see in the Outline section you can see getters and setters are created you can use either @Data or @Getter
@Setter 
On top of class or you can give on top of variable

```
@Getter @Setter
privateString riverName;
```

{OR}

```
@Getter
@Setter
Class River{
String riverName;
}
```

[OR]

```
@Data
class River 
{
Private String riverName;

}
```

You can see the project structure and Outline Structure how it got created in simple steps.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the 'F:\' from -javaagent

`-vm E:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\bin`

`-vmargs`

`-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7`

`-javaagent:\Tools\Java Lib\Lombok\lombok.jar`

`-Xbootclasspath/a:F:\Tools\Java Lib\Lombok\lombok.jar`

`-Xms40m`

`-Xmx512m`

Comment: I needed to give absolute path of `lombok-1.16.16.jar` downlaoded from 
 [Lombak website](https://projectlombok.org/download) to `eclipse.ini` under both `javaagent` and `Xbootclasspath`.

Answer (score 1):

I have met with the exact same problem. 
And it turns out that the configuration file generated by gradle asks for java1.7.
While my system has java1.8 installed.

After modifying the compiler compliance level to 1.8. All things are working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Windows, please select "run as administrator" for the command prompt for executing the java app (ie: for executing  java -jar ${your_jar_path}\lombok-1.14.6.jar).

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Goto https://projectlombok.org/download and click on 1.18.2

Step 2: Place your jar file in  java installation path in my case it is C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1\lib

step 3: Open your Eclipse  IDE folder where you have in your PC.

Step 4: Add the place where I added then open your IDE it will open without any errors.

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.0.v20180512-1130.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.700.v20180518-1200
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
-showsplash
org.eclipse.epp.package.common
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-javaagent:C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1\lib\lombok.jar
-Xbootclasspath/a:C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1\lib\lombok.jar
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
```

Answer (score 0):

While installing lombok in ubuntu machine with `java -jar lombok.jar` you may find following error:

java.awt.AWTError: Assistive Technology not found: org.GNOME.Accessibility.AtkWrapper

You can overcome this by simply doing following steps:

Step 1: 
This can be done by editing the accessibility.properties file of JDK:

```
sudo gedit /etc/java-8-openjdk/accessibility.properties
```

Step 2:
Comment (#) the following line:

```
assistive_technologies=org.GNOME.Accessibility.AtkWrapper
```

Answer (score 0):

For `Gradle` users, if you are using Eclipse or one of its offshoots(I am using STS `4.5.1.RELEASE`), all that you need to do is:

- In build.gradle, you **ONLY** need these 2 "extra" instructions:

  ```
  dependencies {
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'  
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
  }
  ```
- Right-click on your project > Gradle > Refresh Gradle Project. The `lombok-"version".jar` will appear inside your project's **Project and External Dependencies**
- Right-click on that `lombok-"version".jar` > Run As > Java Application (similar to double-clicking on the actual jar or running `java -jar lombok-"version".jar` on the command line.)
- A GUI will appear, follow the instructions and one of the thing it does is to copy `lombok.jar` to your IDE's root.

**Note: Remember to restart your IDE and clean all your previously compiled files.**

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the lombok maven dependency to your pom
2. Download lombok.jar and run java -jar lombok.jar to add it to your eclipse installation
3. Ensure to edit the project specific settings to enable the annotation processing
   Right click on your project > click on Properties > search for annotation >
   Enable project specific settings and Enable annotation Processing

source: https://nawaman.net/blog/2017-11-05

Answer (score 0):

## for Mac/ Windows

first add the dependency on the pom.xml
if using started project then add this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

if you add this you have to change the plugin section also
it'll look something like this

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

else add the dependency from maven

then follow this link
https://projectlombok.org/setup/eclipse

Answer (score 0):

For Mac :

1. Download lombok from [Lombok downloads](https://projectlombok.org/download)
2. `cd` into the folder where lombok.jar is placed
3. `sudo java -jar lombok.jar`
4. Click on `Specify location` and browse to `eclipse.ini` and select it.
   ( Path will be similar to :  /Users/jay/Desktop/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/eclipse.ini)
5. Click `install` button and `restart` eclipse.