# ProjectLombok - Method Undefined in Eclipse After Installing Eclipse Luna

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, lombok

I downloaded Eclipse Luna and imported a stable existing Maven project which makes use of the @Getter and @Setter lombok annotations.  The annotations are recognized, but Eclipse flags any calls to the getter or setter methods giving the error message

> The method getSomething() is undefined for the type Foo

Unlike other stackoverflow questions, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418865/cannot-make-project-lombok-work-on-eclipse-helios), I am experiencing this issue despite the fact that I have updated my eclipse.ini, and added the lombok.jar to the same directory as my eclipse.exe and eclipse.ini file.  The eclipse.ini changes made no difference though, I still have error markets everywhere!

**eclipse.ini**

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\javaw.exe
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-javaagent:lombok.jar
-Xbootclasspath/a:lombok.jar
```

I have done a project > clean, I have tried using the full path to my lombok jar, I have exited and restarted Eclipse all to no avail.

What am I missing here?  Thanks for any help!!!

Comment: try running mvn dependency:tree

Comment: I ran mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=org.project.lombok.  This is not a command I use much, but everything looks fine.. it finds the lombok jar.  Should I be looking for anything specific?

Comment: I guess that getting Lombok running with mvn and Eclipse are two rather completely unrelated things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I experienced this issue because the lombok version my project used, 0.9.3, was not supported in Eclipse Luna.  I have upgraded my version to 1.14.8 and now everything is working as expected.

See [how to configure lombok in eclipse luna](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22310414/how-to-configure-lombok-in-eclipse-luna) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Actually no real idea, but maybe something helps.

Eclipse uses its own compiler, while Maven probably uses `javac`. So you normally have to get noth running and these two things are unrelated.

A single Eclipse restart was always sufficient for me.

Look in Help / About Eclipse SDK: Is there an Lombok entry?

My eclipse.ini contains absolute paths:

```
-javaagent:/home/maaartin/eclipse/lombok.jar
-Xbootclasspath/a:/home/maaartin/eclipse/lombok.jar
```

but relative path must work too. The question is "relative to what?".

Normally, Lombok can find your Eclipse install directory and install itself. You have to do it manually, only when using non-standard install directories.

Open the Error Log View, maybe there's something bad going on. Just in case, look at the log files on the disk, too.

[image: Eclipse-Lombok.png]

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Can you please elaborate a bit as to how I would tell if there is a lombok entry in Help > About?  I kept my prior version of Eclipse (Kepler), where Lombok works great, but I didn't find any Lombok reference.  The error logs are mostly the same, the differences I found are related to the Help documentation not being indexed properly in Eclipse Luna

Comment: @JayProck The last row in the picture, I've just added. Other than that, no idea... you can try the mailing list, but the authors seem to be rather busy with other work.

Comment: Thanks for posting the screenshot. I believe that was included with later versions of lombok.  I'm using version 0.9.3.  It's definitely helpful to know I will get that verification if I move to a more recent lombok version.

Answer (score 0):

Maven repository for Project Lombok is set under provided scope at project home page

http://projectlombok.org/mavenrepo/

Just remove that scope and it works on Eclipse Luna with version 1.14.8.