# Configuring lombok for gradle project in eclipse Luna/Mars

Tags: eclipse, gradle, lombok

I have followed [how to configure lombok in eclipse luna](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22310414/how-to-configure-lombok-in-eclipse-luna) but it is not working for me for [a given gradle project](https://github.com/universal-automata/liblevenshtein-java/blob/master/build.gradle), against the latest version of lombok, having tried both eclipse Luna and Mars.

I have installed lombok to my eclipse through `java -jar lombok.jar`, providing it the path to my eclipse installation in the UI dialog that it opens up.

I have also added the jar to the project, as seen below.
[image]

I added the following argument to the java command in my desktop launch script (this is Ubuntu)

```
-vmargs -javaagent:lombok.jar
```

(relative and absolute paths worked the same).

The project is a gradle project, and it builds perfectly fine outside of eclipse.

What might be missing, or, how would I further troubleshoot it?

Comment: I read this twice, but I cannot figure out, what the problem is. Is eclipse building, but gradle not? Or other way around? Or nothing at all?

Comment: Eclipse highlights swaths of the source code as erroneous, as if it does not run lombok before compiling, whereas gradle is buildling just fine outside of eclipse (and also inside eclipse).

Comment: In Eclipse, in the Help/About Eclipse you should see a line like `
Lombok v1.16.8 "Candid Duck" is installed. https://projectlombok.org/`. If you don't see the line, Lombok is not installed correctly. Do you see such line?