# Eclipse displaying compilation error messages while using lombok API

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, lombok

I am using lombok API in my codebase to generate getter and setter functionality internally for DTO. Here is one example.

```
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class TemplateDTO {
    private String templateId;

    private String templateName;

}
```

The issue is while using the get/set methods of TemplateDTO in my codebase eclipse is showing me error messages.

However maven install is working fine (if I run via the command line).

Is there anyway I can disable error messages in eclipse or is there anyway I can resolve getter and setter code?

I am using Eclipse Neon.2 Release (4.6.2) in OSX.

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: Have you tried these solutions?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3425327/8269819
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21996257/8269819

Comment: How to configure Lombok in Eclipse, see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22310414/how-to-configure-lombok-in-eclipse-luna

Comment: @Steve It's  compilation error, that getter and setters are not there in DTO class.

Answer (score 4):

I will answer this question myself. Thanks to lukjar and @MrSimpleMind response.

Just append following lines in eclipse.ini.

Basically add lombok.jar in your javaagent and Xbootclasspath arguments.

```
-Xbootclasspath/a:/Users/test/lombok/lombok.jar
-javaagent:/Users/test/lombok/lombok.jar
```

After this

1. restart eclipse
2. Run `maven clean install`
3. Refresh eclipse workspace

It's good to go now.

Comment: Recent versions of lombok no longer need the -Xbootclasspath/a parameter. I don't know the exact version number but at least 1.16.14, probably a lot earlier.

Comment: You could have use the lombok built-in eclipse installer: `java -jar lombok.jar`

Comment: Thanks @RoelSpilker for reply. Yes 'java -jar lombok.jar' is also one of the way to use it.