# Lombok/Eclipse Issues - I can compile but I cannot run

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, lombok

I'm having an issue with Lombok or Eclipse, not sure which. I have a Spring Boot maven project for which I am using Lombok. I've added this in my pom.xml file and I've used the lombok install for eclipse.

Whats happening is that I can do a `mvn clean` and a `mvn install` and a maven update on the project and everything builds as expected. As soon as I go to run the project errors start to appear and I get error such as:

```
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The method getxxx() is undefined for the type xxxxxx
```

Is there anything that can happen when running the project that can some how strip out lombok?!

I'm running Eclipse Oxygen (4.7.3) with lombok v1.16.18 "Dancing Elephant" any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: That's because your getter and setter methods aren't generated in your `.class` files when you run the project. Please check [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11807022/3669624) for more details.

Comment: That sounds like the issue to me, however when I follow the instructions in the answer to provided I still get the same issue :(

Comment: What version of Java are you targeting? I've had similar issues with Java 9 and Java 10. Java 8 is the only one that seems to work perfectly.

Comment: Did you also do `mvn eclipse:eclipse` after adding lombok to the pom? Also, are you running the project from within Eclipse, or from maven/appassembler/whatever?

Comment: I'm using Java 8, strangely it has been working perfectly. Only recently this has started to occur. I've rolled back to a version which worked but im still seeing the issue

Comment: @tobias_k yeah I did, I'm running it from within Eclipse

Comment: Still not entirely clear. You say you can build the project with maven (`mvn install`), but can you also (a) run it with maven/from command line, (b) compile it in Eclipse (no squigly red lines), (c) run it in Eclipse?

Comment: @SpaceCowboy Try to close and start eclipse after adding lombok and executing the suggested command, if you check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22332248/3669624) as well, it's stating the same thing.

Comment: I can build with mvn clean/install in eclipse, also on the commandline, but I can't run it from anywhere as it complains about missing getters/setters

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how exactly in eclipse, but in the ​​Intellij IDEA I need to install the lombok plugin in the settings, I suspect that in eclipse also it needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

Here is tested link for setting up lombok for the eclipse as well as intellij.

https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-ide

Answer (score 0):

Adding the tag `<annotationProcessorPaths>` to pom.xml solved my same problem.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        <version>RELEASE</version>
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
                ...
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps I followed to resolve this:

**Step1**: Download Lombok Jar File & Install it.

**Step2**: edit C:/Program Files/Eclipse/eclipse.ini , & provide path of lombok jar in this file like below:

`-javaagent:H:\Jars\lombok-1.18.24.jar`

**Step3**: Restart Eclipse : project > clean