# Class see methods generated by lombok Data as undefined Eclipse

Tags: java, spring-boot, lombok

I am learnig Java Spring. While learning, I noticed that other classes see the methods generated by lombok as undefined.
[image]

But if I press Ctrl + Space I can see them:[image]

Class with variables showing them to on Outline:
[image]

Does anyone know what's wrong? I probably made some stupid configuration mistake but I can't find it myself and I can't find help on Google.

Comment: There is nothing wrong per-se. The program should still compile just fine (given, of course, you use the lombok preprocessor). This seems to be an error / a misconfiguration of the lombok plugin in eclipse.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22310414/how-to-configure-lombok-in-eclipse-luna

Comment: Thanks for both of you, problem was with elipse.ini. I added the needed lines in wrong place, now all work.