# lombok-1.14.6.jar error the method getDob() is undefined for the type ***

Tags: java, lombok

I have added lombok-1.14.6 in my eclipse (helios) for my application. I am getting the error for all get methods. Like

```
The method getSex() is undefined for the type ***


The method getSex() is undefined for the type ***
```

I have added lombok jar file in eclipse.
I don't know what is the issue. Help me.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you see the instructions on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418865/cannot-make-project-lombok-work-on-eclipse-helios? Disclosure: I am a Lombok developer.

Comment: may the great spaghetti monster bless you for developing Lombok for us sir :)