# Lombok and STS issue - Method undefined

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite, eclipse-luna, lombok

I have STS version 3.6.3.SR1 that's based on Eclipse Luna 4.4.1.

I did the following steps:

1. Download and run the Lombok runnable jar and gave the path of my STS.
2. I verified the entries of `vmargs`, but was missing `Xbootclasspath` and added it resulting in

   ```
   -vmargs -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
   -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
   -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion=10001
   -Xms512m
   -Xmx1024m
   -javaagent:C:\tools\Lombok\lombok.jar
   -Xbootclasspath/a:C:\tools\Lombok\lombok.jar
   ```
3. I exit and opened the STS both from shortcut as well as the absolute location of the `STS.exe`.
4. I verified the outline of my Java classes that are annotated with `@Data` and other Lombok annotations. I can see the getters and setters generated. Even auto assist displays the method.
5. I did Maven → Update Project and even did a Project Clean
6. Confirmed that the Lombok is installed as well from the 'About STS' of 'Help'.

Even after all the above activities, there are lots of compiler issues that complains undefined method `getXXX()` and `setXXX()` on all `@Data` or `@Getter` or `@Setter` annotations.

Maven build runs successfully and the runtime behavior is fine, as the complied class seems to have the getters and setters.

IntelliJ seems to have no porblem with this as other developers are able to use the library.

My `pom.xml` has the following entry as well:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.16.4</version>
</dependency>
```

How do I resolve?

***P.S : I downloaded Eclipse Kepler build on top of STS to enable JBoss Fuse Tooling.***

Comment: Hmm., sometimes you will have to start eclipse/STS as an administrator and then clean and rebuild the project. This helped me. I just tried this and it worked. I too got vexed by the above workarounds. Good luck! Too late, but it might help others.

Comment: Cool. I switched to IntelliJ meanwhile and been using since then :) Since the admin rights are managed by organization, couldn't have tried it. Thank you though.

Answer (score 8):

@Karthik R, thanks for your post. The following helped me to solve the issue:

1. Go to [the Lombok page](https://projectlombok.org/) and download and double-click the jar and install in your IDE.
2. After that, open the `.ini` file and see if it has **`javaagent`** and **`Xbootclasspath`** variables.

In my case, **`Xbootclasspath`** was missing and when I added that, it worked.

---

```
-Xbootclasspath/a:PATH_To_lambok.jar
```

Answer (score 6):

I added `-Xbootclasspath/a:lombok.jar` like [naga1990 mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40348004), however it still didn't solve the issue. After starting STS with `-clean` it did work.

Comment: This worked for me. On Linux, go to the folder containing the STS file, and on the console run `./STS -clean`. I guess in Windows, it would be the same with the .exe

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem which was resolved by changing the scope of the Lombok dependency in the `pom.xml` file.

Originally, the scope was "provided" and I believe I saw all the strange behaviors you described. For instance, the context-sensitive code completion pulldown included the getter and setter methods. When I chose a getter method from the pulldown, the method was inserted into the source correctly. After insertion of the getter method, STS marked the method invocation as a compilation error because it thought the method did not exist.

After removing the "provided" scope from the Lombok dependency, STS worked correctly and the getter/setter methods could be added to code, the code could be compiled/packaged and executed. Execution of the getter/setter methods worked.

Comment: Thx, this helped me as well. Many Thx!

Answer (score 3):

If you already tried other methods but it still doesn't work, you can try this:

If your project is **Maven-based project**, STS configured it as **AspectJ Capability** which will conflict with **Lombok**.

To solve it, remove Aspects Capability by **Right-click the project -> AspectJ Tools -> Remove AspectJ Capability**. Hope this will work.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I solved it as follows...
1. downloaded UI Swing application of lombok ... namely lombok.jar
2. started it and entered path of sts manually till sts.exe, i.e. complete folder which contains sts.exe
3. clicked on update/install
4. while doing all above 3 steps, make sure that sts is not running at all.
5. start sts
6. clean build the project.

Answer (score 2):

This if for eclipse/STS
1. Close your sdk
2. download lombok jar
3. double click it or run it with java.exe 
4. Make sure below line should get added in .ini file
       -javaagent:\lombok.jar
5. add below line if missing add yourself
       -Xbootclasspath/\lombok.jar
6. Open your sdk. Go to Help->About. You should see below line
       "Lombok v1.18.6 "Envious Ferret" is installed. https://projectlombok.org/"
7. Clean your project.
8. Build it again.

Answer (score 2):

Try to close your project, open it again and check. It worked for me.

Comment: This , sometimes we miss to try the simple things.

Answer (score 0):

After adding javaagent and Xbootclasspath values. Close STS completely and start again. Don't try to restart, it will not work

Answer (score 0):

If all answers do not work, remove the **lombok** dependency from ***pom.xml*** file of the project and then save/build the project.
Then, again add the **lombok** dependency to ***pom.xml*** and save/build the project.

This worked for me!!!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and it turns out that lombok is not working only when I'm starting STS from desktop shortcut which I created earlier (before loombok installed). I removed shortcut and created once again and lombok works fine. Please try this solution if you are using shortcut to run your sts.