# Lombok does not work for Eclipse Neon

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, lombok

I downloaded lombok.jar (lombok-1.16.14.jar) put it into my Downloads. Then I clicked on this jar, the execution correctly identifies the Eclipse instances on my MacOS and then I selected the instance I want.  Lombok is also specified in the pom.xml
    
      org.projectlombok
      lombok
       1.16.14
       provided

In eclipse.ini I got the addition:
-javaagent:../Eclipse/lombok.jar

lombok.jar was added to the same directory as eclise.ini
/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse

I am still getting setter/getter errors in Eclipse Problems despite that my `mvn` build works fine.

The code for a User:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EntityListeners(UserListener.class)
public class User implements Serializable, UserDetails {
...
```

The error:

```
The method getRole() is undefined for the type User
```

Comment: Add lombok as dependency?

Comment: It is already there:  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

Comment: User has getRole method for sure?

Comment: I see you're using an annotation `@EntityListeners` that's not from Lombok, maybe is there some conflict between those annotation processors? Lombok changed something to be able to be compatible with some other processors in last version https://projectlombok.org/changelog.html

Comment: restart the eclipse and build the project from eclipse. sometimes eclipse fails to sync its project tree with the actual project

Comment: Not sure about Eclipse, but in IntelliJ I had to enable annotation processors. Maybe you can check those settings?

Comment: I did "project -> clean all projects" after adding the javaagent to eclipse.ini and it eliminated the error messages.  Not using maven, just eclipse builders.

Comment: hope this will be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46034044/2987755

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, downloading the latest Eclipse Neon, i.e. Neon 3, fixed the problem

Answer (score 51):

Since you have already added the .jar to your `lib` folder, then go to the `lib`
and execute `java -jar lombok-1.16.4.jar`, you'll see a wizard, specify the location of your `eclipse.ini`, after you are done with this your `eclipse.ini` file should look like this:

```
    -vmargs
    ...
    -javaagent:lombok.jar
    -Xbootclasspath/a:lombok.jar
```

For me this just worked fine but I found in other answers that:

- You should not **just** "restart" Eclipse, go to `File -> Exit` and then open it again. [taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3419385/1535071)
- Don't forget to do a `mvn clean` just to make sure that you recompiled your classes. [taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20314384/1535071)
- After all this you should also right-click on your project, then `Maven -> Update Project` [taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21996257/1535071)

Comment: I see -javaagent:../Eclipse/lombok.jar after running lombok.jar. But i do not see  -Xbootclasspath/a:lombok.jar.

Comment: @AlexNarinsky Please try adding the line manually and let me know

Comment: did not help either

Comment: @AlexNarinsky maybe you have a similar problem like mentioned in my answer (i.e. that just the desktop-link does not respect the settings defined in eclipse.ini). You could check that by simply starting eclipse from the command line using the `eclipse` executable next to the `eclipse.ini`. If its working, you see something like  "Lombok ... is installed" in "Help"->"About Eclipse".

Comment: perfect! the "not just restart eclipse" hint solved my problem.

Comment: I did "project -> clean all projects" after adding the javaagent to eclipse.ini and it eliminated the error messages.  Not using maven, just eclipse builders.

Answer (score 13):

There is a manual way to install `lombok` under eclipse, I do not checked it, but it maybe helps you -

1. copy `lombok.jar` to where your eclipse folder where is the `eclipse.ini`
2. open `eclipse.ini`，put at end the below two lines below and save it

   ```
   -Xbootclasspath/a:lombok.jar
   -javaagent:lombok.jar
   ```
3. restart  `eclipse`.

Comment: manual way to install `lombok` under eclipse: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46034044/2987755

Comment: year 2020, lombok does not need manual configuration for eclipse, except, manually press the button `clean` project!!!

Answer (score 6):

I had the problem, that **the link, which I used to start eclipse, didnt respect the eclipse.ini file**.

My environment is:

```
IDE: Version: Neon.0 Release (4.6.0)
OS: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
```

The installation routine `java -jar lombok-1.16.16.jar` works quite well. I.e. it adds the reasonable line `-javaagent:<ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_ECLIPSE_INSTALLATION>/lombok.jar` to the `eclipse.ini`.

But if I start eclipse by **using my desktop-shortcut**, it starts without lombok (checked by looking at "Help"->"About Eclipse").
If I start eclipse by executing the executable `eclipse` next to the `eclipse.ini` file, lombok launches like a charm.

Hence I checked my desktop shortcut (e.g. `~/.local/share/applications/eclipse.desktop`) and indeed, it started eclipse without reflecting the `eclipse.ini`.
Instead it uses something like `/usr/bin/java -jar org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.jar ...` to start eclipse.

So the solution was to replace the old `Exec` line in the desktop shortcut by:

```
Exec=/opt/eclipse/neon/eclipse
```

where `/opt/eclipse/neon/` is the place where I have installed eclipse.

Answer (score 5):

[Antoniolazaro](https://github.com/antoniolazaro) has given a solution for Eclipse Neon issue on MacOS

When I put the complete path, it works on Mac Os.

```
-javaagent:/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/lombok.jar
```

### Resource Link:

1. https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1173

And the lombok project owner [rzwitserloot](https://github.com/rzwitserloot) has given 3 suggestions for checking

1. Can you give us the complete path, from root, of your eclipse
   install? Starting with 1.16.14, the installer should still find
   eclipse even with the funky paths that the OOM installer comes up
   with. I have no idea why the installer isn't finding your eclipse
   automatically, here. I can't reproduce this on my mac.
2. The lombok uninstaller has the same `'find eclipses'` capability as
   the installer. `Mac doesn't have a registry and we aren't going to
   dump a bunch of crud in your homedir just to keep track of where we
   installed your lombok;` we like it that way: No cruft. So, that part
   (that the uninstaller can't find a custom-install location and
   requires you to again specify it) is not a bug.
3. You still have to add `lombok.jar` to your project as a dependency
   same as any other third party dependency (something like guava, for
   example). It's not clear from your problem description if you
   actually did that.

### Resource Link:

https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1310

Comment: Please, read the updated description.  Specifying the full path did not help

Comment: @AlexNarinsky Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 3):

Even after following the below steps(try the steps given below first) , if it doesn't works, one issue can be that you are using the eclipse from the desktop , not from the folder where eclipse is installed. Running eclipse from the desktop sometimes is unable to load the .ini file, hence lombok won't run. So, ***try running the eclipse from the folder where you have installed it***.

Steps:
 1. Give the lombok dependency in the pom and build it.

2. The lombok.jar is usually downloaded in the folder **.m2/repository/org/projectlombok/lombok/1.x.y**
3. Install the jar in the folder "**java -jar lombok-1.x.y.jar**"
4. Then it will ask you to select the IDE. Browse to the eclipse installation 
   folder and select eclipse from there.
5. Now your eclipse installation folder, should contain the lombok.jar and eclipse.ini should contain the line
   -javaagent: /lombok.jar
6. Run the eclipse from the installation folder. Clean and rebuild the project. 
   *It should work now!*

Comment: This is actually one of the BEST replies - thank you!  See my explanation below.

Answer (score 1):

try @Data annotation for the class.

```
public @Data class user{
 \\do stuff
 }
```

Comment: Did not help, i am also getting "Data cannot be resolved to a type ".  I also added: import lombok.Data;

Answer (score 1):

My environment is:

```
IDE: Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)
OS: Ubuntu 16.4
```

It works for me when i do this steps below:

```
1. copy `lombok.jar` to where your eclipse folder where is the `eclipse.ini` ;
2. open `eclipse.ini`，put at end the two lines below with full lombok path and save it：
    -Xbootclasspath/a:/DEV/Tools/IDE/eclipse/jee-neon/lombok.jar
    -javaagent:/DEV/Tools/IDE/eclipse/jee-neon/lombok.jar
3. restart  `eclipse` in command line (when i try run with exist link in launcher it's not work)
4. rebuild your projects
```

Comment: Hello @rafambbr, since you mentioned that using the existing link to start eclipse didnt start lombok, you may check your `Exec` command that is used by the desktop-link.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am concerned, I use a "Chocolatey" distribution of Eclipse on Windows.

It does not change much. But for those of you who are not admin of their desktop, it might be a hassle, because Chocolatey installs softwares in `C:\ProgramData\...` which is an "admin" directory.

In other words, you may need to modify your shortcut's property "start in" which will not be possible unless you are admin of your desktop.

The trick that worked for me here was to create a new shortcut, which has the correct "start in" property to start eclipse in the directory where the eclipse.ini is...

Then recompile using eclipse, then work on your project a bit until eclipse realizes that lombok was installed...

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

After installing lombok, you need to copy lombok.jar into your project or add dependency in maven configuration xml file

Answer (score 0):

exit the eclipse and then go to the eclipse directory and open `eclipse.ini` and add `-clean` on a top and rerun the eclipse. hope your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on the above replies:

- PROBLEM:

  In my scenario:

  1. I installed SpringBoot STS under `Eclipse Photon`,
  2. I created a`Spring Boot/Gradle build` project, and I got the "undefined method" error using Lombok `@Data`.
  3. Environment: Ubuntu Linux 18.04.
- SOLUTION:

  1. cd ~/.gradle/cache/.../lombok/...;
  2. java -jar lombok-1.16.22.jar
- NOTE:

  `java -jar lombok*.jar` brings up a GUI that

  1. Allows you to select which Eclipse install to update.
  2. Updates eclipse.ini *AND*...
  3. Copies `lombok-xyz.jar` into the Eclipse install folder, as `lombok.jar`.

Answer (score 0):

Eventhough there are already a lot of answers here none of the given answers solved my problem, so I'll add my information here as well in case it might help someone:

```
My setup is:
Win10 Home,
Eclipse Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a),
Eclipse Build id: 20180405-1200,
```

1. Add lombok to my pom.xml
2. mvn clean install
3. close eclipse
4. navigate to my .m2 folder `.m2\repository\org\projectlombok\lombok\1.18.6>`
5. run: `java -jar .\lombok-1.18.6.jar` (or whatever version you have
6. Install lombok

Now it's getting intresting. The installation added the following to my eclipse.ini:

```
-javaagent:lombok.jar
```

How ever it placed them at the bottom of my .ini file. So it looked liked this.

```
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-...
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-javaagent:lombok.jar
```

I assumed that `-javaagent:lombok.jar` belongs under `-vmargs`so I put it at the bottom of `--launcher.appendVmargs`. That didn't work either though. But when I put `-javaagent:lombok.jar`right below `vmargs` it works. Ultimately my eclipse.ini looks like this:

```
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-javaagent:lombok.jar # lombok works for me if this is here
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
- Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
#-javaagent:lombok.jar | lombok doesn't work for me if its placed here.
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
```

Not sure why this issue orcurrs but maybe it helps you. If you are under macOS remember to add `-Xbootclasspath/a:lombok.ja`like other answers in this thread suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue recently and all the above solutions mentioned by the above users didn't work. The problem I have was there are special symbols like '$' in path(This can be found in last line of eclipse.ini file) to eclipse. Due to the same reason lombok cannot identify the file and append the necessary two lines in eclipse.ini file. Removing the special characters like '-' , '$', '_' in my eclipse path fixed mu problem

Answer (score 0):

For, after installing lombok like mentioned above I had to do right click on your project folder -> Run as -> Maven clean. Ne the .jar is deteced and properly used

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy and paste the lombok jar into the eclipse installation folder.
2. Run the command "java -jar lombok-.jar".
3. A GUI opens.
4. Check the IDE listed in the installer.
5. This entry should be available in the eclipse.ini file "-javaagent:<>".
6. Restart Eclipse to find the changes which starts listing the associated getters, setters in your java file.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add to eclipse.ini file this statement (or check if you have):

> -Xbootclasspath/a:lombok.jar
>
> -javaagent:lombok.jar

Attention please, usually you have only:

> -javaagent:lombok.jar

Obviously **restart your eclipse**

Answer (score 0):

For Eclipse neon on Mac (High Sierra) :

- Use lombok version 1.16.14 or above.
- Installer launches by running (double clicking) `lombok-1.16.14.jar` file itself. It should detect installed versions.
- On the Mac, it detects Eclipse.app only from Applications directory. If not, you can tell the jar where to find it in the popup dialog. Note that you should point it to `eclipse.ini` file (Eclipse.app -> Show app contents -> eclipse -> eclipse.ini)
- Lower versions of lombok do not work on High Sierra. They don't detect installed eclipse instances.
- Finally remember to restart eclipse (via File -> exit) and run maven update project.

Answer (score 0):

I might be late to reply here but for future references adding this answer,

1. Please don't use Lombok v1.18.14 as it will crash eclipse. It is mentioned in [changelogs](https://projectlombok.org/changelog). Use next version v1.18.16.
2. Simple way to setup lombok to eclipse is mentioned in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/69332138/3637115