# Lombok problems with Eclipse Oxygen

Tags: eclipse, lombok

I upgraded recently to the new Eclipse version (Oxygen). I downloaded the lombok.jar from the website and installed it. This is how the `eclipse.ini` looks like after installation:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
--launcher.library
C:\Users\xxx\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.500.v20170531-1133
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
-showsplash
org.eclipse.epp.package.common
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
-javaagent:lombok.jar
```

I can use Lombok as seen here:

[image: pojoclass] [image: outlineinfo]

But when using the getters/setters and/or constructors in other classes I get the this errors:

[image: codeInfo] [image]

Also these are my Eclipse and Lombok versions:

```
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Oxygen Release (4.7.0)
Build id: 20170620-1800
Lombok v1.16.18 "Dancing Elephant" is installed. https://projectlombok.org/
```

Anyone knows how I can fix it?

Comment: It may be an issue with the annotation processor. Check if it is turned on.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that the @Override annotation is not working either? That's not the case tho.

Comment: My problem solved was at my office computer when I run eclipse as administrator. (ofc after the lombok installation)

Answer (score 110, accepted):

My env: java version `1.8.0_144`

**Eclipse:**

- Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
- Version: Oxygen Release (4.7.0)
- Build id: 20170620-1800

**Steps:**

1. Exit Eclipse(if it is open) and downloaded jar from https://projectlombok.org/download
2. execute command: `java -jar lombok.jar`
3. This command will open window as shown here https://projectlombok.org/setup/eclipse, install and quit the installer.
4. Add jar to build path/add it to pom.xml.

e.g. for Gradle build

```
 annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok")
 compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok")
```

5. restart eclipse.
6. Go to Eclipse --> About Eclipse --> check 'Lombok v1.16.18 "Dancing Elephant" is installed. [https://projectlombok.org/'](https://projectlombok.org/%27)
7. To enable Lombok for the project: `Enable annotation processing` in the respective IDE.
   That's it. It worked.
   I did not change eclipse init script.

> Note: Read the note in following image regarding -vm options **If you start
> Eclipse with a custom -vm parameter, you'll need to add:**

```
-vmargs -javaagent:<path-to-lombok-jar>/lombok.jar
```

> **as parameter as well**

Above steps works for `Photon Release (4.8.0)` - `Lombok v1.18.2`, `eclipse: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)` - `Lombok v1.18.0` and `eclipse: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)` - `Lombok v1.18.2`

lombok success screen:
[image]

fyi,
For JDK - 10 and 11 [support](https://projectlombok.org/changelog):
Lombok version should be at least v1.18.4 (October 30th, 2018) or higher.

Comment: BTW, I believe the installer does change your eclipse.ini, saving you the trouble of doing it by hand.

Comment: This worked like a charm.But why does work with eclipse-oxygen and not with eclipse-photon??

Comment: @dkb I used photon and the getter and setter methods never got resolved what ever I may do until I realized that the eclipse didn't have lombok while the project had. Thank you.

Comment: Ohh, got it, @Eswar, fyi, you need to install Lombok plugin for IntelliJ-idea ide too in case if you wish to use in future.

Comment: For me eclipse didn´t start after installing Lombok. I modified the eclipse.ini file specifiying the path to lombock.jar `-javaagent:C:\YOUR_PATH_TO_ECLIPSE\eclipse\lombok.jar`

Comment: @LorenzoLerate what error you got while starting eclipse?

Comment: @dkb something similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333874/eclipse-startup-error-code-1

Comment: @LorenzoLerate As it is mentioned in a screenshot above, `If you start Eclipse with a custom -vm parameter, you'll need to add: -vmargs -javaagent:lombok.jar as parameter as well.` I think you might have -vm parameter in eclipse.ini file.

Comment: I did and Eclipse didn't start. I had to put the full path

Comment: @LorenzoLerate updated answer with your suggestions, thank you!

Comment: Yes, the installer definitely does change your eclipse.ini. It tells you so if you click on the link in the installer to "show me how you will change my installation" or something similar. The two things the installer does are to copy itself to the same directory as your eclipse.ini, and to add a line with that path (the path to the copied jar) to your eclipse.ini.

Comment: @dkb as exactly as this problem mentioned above, Eclipse doesn't identify getters and setters. `The method getId() is undefined for the type...`

Comment: @ChamithraThenuwara which eclipse version, which jdk version and lombok version?

Comment: @dkb Eclipse Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a), java version "1.8.0_221", Lombok v1.16.14 "Candid Duck"

Comment: @ChamithraThenuwara, try with lombok: v1.18.0, any reason to use older lombok version?

Comment: @dkb that's the version my organization uses

Comment: Thank you very much...I just learnt few things :)

Answer (score 30):

For MacBook Pro users (e.g. running **macOs** Sierra v10.12.6), in order to install [lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) on [Eclipse Oxygen (4.7.0) or Photon (4.8.0)](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/oomph/epp/oxygen/R/eclipse-inst-mac64.tar.gz), using Java 1.8 (1.8.0_144), just do the following actions:

1. Download *lombok* from the site [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/download);
2. Close your Eclipse IDE if it is open;
3. Trigger *lombok* installation either by following the [official installation steps](https://projectlombok.org/setup/eclipse) or by executing the command: `java -jar lombok.jar`;
4. If the *lombok* installer doesn't find your Eclipse IDE, you will be requested to enter the path to your Eclipse. You should input the path to your *eclipse.ini* file. In my case was `/tools/ide/eclipse/jee-oxygen/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/eclipse.ini`.
5. Quit the installer and open Eclipse.
6. On the menu bar, go to *Eclipse > About Eclipse* and validate that *lombok* is installed:

   ```
   Lombok v1.16.18 "Dancing Elephant" is installed. https://projectlombok.org/
   ```

   Be sure to scroll the text window down since the installed Lombok version appears in the text above the row of icons.
7. Finally, add *lombok* to your project's build path according to the building tool you're using. For Maven, for instance, use the following dependency:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
       <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
       <version>1.16.18</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
   ```

Comment: When you're looking in the Eclipse > About Eclipse box to verify Lombok is installed, be sure to scroll the text window down.  What you're looking for appears in the text above the row of icons.  Also, be sure to force a clean build of your project.

Comment: @KCBaltz you're absolutely right! I'll update my post accordingly.

Answer (score 10):

[Lombok does not work for Eclipse Neon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42444457/lombok-does-not-work-for-eclipse-neon)

> ```
>  - You should not just "restart" Eclipse, go to File -> Exit and then
>    open it again.
>  - Don't forget to do a mvn clean just to make sure that you recompiled your classes. 
>  - After all this you should also right-click on your project, then Maven -> Update Project
> ```

Comment: Actually this worked for me                                                                                          Eclipse IDE 
Version: 2020-09 (4.17.0)
Build id: 20200910-1200

Answer (score 8):

I faced the same issue and struggled a lot to solve this issue. I was trying with lombok v1.18.14 which fails to setup on eclipse (as mentioned in [changelog](https://projectlombok.org/changelog)) so ensure you don't use it.

The below solution worked for me and it is simple to implement.
This solution works for almost all eclipse versions.

1. In eclipse, goto 'Help'-> 'Install New Software ..'
2. Enter https://projectlombok.org/p2 in 'Work with' and press Enter. Now it should look like below
   [image]
3. Select 'Lombok' and continue to setup. Once it is installed, restart eclipse.

To ensure Lombok is successfully installed, please follow below steps (after restarting eclipse) :

1. In eclipse, goto 'Help'-> 'About Eclipse IDE'.
2. In open dialog box, scroll down if necessary and check for below line
   'Lombok v1.xx.xx "Envious Ferret" is installed. [https://projectlombok.org/'](https://projectlombok.org/%27)

Comment: Note: Sometimes "Restart" eclipse doesn't work so instead the user should "Exit" and Start eclipse again.

Answer (score 7):

I had exactly the same problem with Alex. 
My eclipse version is

> Version: Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a) Build id: 20171005-1200

I installed **lombok 1.16.18**, after checking it was already installed and also javaagent line was added to my eclipse.ini file.

Every thing was fine except that there are compilation errors where getter is called in the project. It's awkward but I fixed by :

1. Cleaning project
2. Building project
3. Restarting eclipse a few times

Nothing else.

Comment: Awesome.. i had to do it twice.

Answer (score 6):

Do not use old versions of java.

What happens is that lombok puts the following line in your eclipse.ini:

```
-javaagent: lombok.jar
```

And lombok.jar is in the `C:\eclipse\jee-oxygen\eclipse` directory

The problem is that the shortcut created by the windows installation looks like this:

[image]

Fill in the "Start at" path and it will work:

[image]

Comment: Life Saver bro! - Thanx alot
I was using:
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
Version: Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a)
Build id: 20171005-1200
OS: Windows 7, v.6.1, x86_64 / win32

Answer (score 6):

Had problems with *Eclipse Oxygen, Java 1.9* and *Lombok* (on *Mac OSX* - *windows/linux* should be similar).

This is what I had to do:

1. Download the latest `lombok: 1.16.20`
2. Open up eclipse, and check for updates and install all of them. Ensure that eclipse is updated to the latest.
3. Exit eclipse.
4. `java -jar lombok.jar`
5. Ensure that the location to Eclipse is correct in the installer window that pops up, I had to explicitly specify:`/[some-folder-heirarchy]/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/eclipse.ini`

Thereafter check to see if the updates have made it in eclipse.ini:

```
-javaagent:/[some_folder-hierarchy]/eclipse-oxygen/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/lombok.jar
```

There is **only one line that is updated**. That is a change from some of the earlier versions of `lombok` where a `bootclasspath` was also specified and / or the path to `lombok.jar` was relative. Now it is an absolute path.

Bring up eclipse and you would see Lombok in action.

And do not forget to use the same `Lombok` version in your `maven` or any other dependency management tool.

*Edit 1:* I also used a different version of `Lombok` in the `maven POM` from the one that is installed in `eclipse` and for the most part, things compiled but there were a few compile errors in `eclipse`. Of course, things compiled successfully on the command line with `maven`. So if you have project dependencies that force you to use different Lombok versions then be aware of such an eventuality. The crux is to have the same version installed in both `eclipse` and in your project's dependency management (`maven` etc.).

Answer (score 4):

For Linux/Ubuntu users who are launching Eclipse from a launcher (a .desktop file) that is locked to your launcher, and your Help --> About dialog doesn't show lombok is installed:

1. Close Eclipse
2. Unlock Eclipse from your launcher
3. Start Eclipse from the .desktop application
4. Verify "Help --> About" indicates lombok is installed (scroll down)
5. Lock to your launcher again

It seems this works due to some issue with applications 'lock to launcher', and it's the unlock/lock process that fixes it.

(Thanks to [cardamon](https://github.com/cardamon)'s comment [here](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1427#issuecomment-322467968) that pointed me to this solution)

Comment: Spent so much time trying to make that thing work until I found your fix. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Thank you, atlast find something that woked

Answer (score 3):

**Solution:**

1. Install lombok 1.16.18 as instructed by lombok website. It's better Eclipse is close during installation.
2. Make sure Eclipse can start up properly. On the shortcut, change the properties, and fill in the "**Start in**" path and it will work as noted by Thomas and Fabiano.
3. Once Eclipse opens, update Maven on the project to solve compilation errors.
4. Now Lombok latest release works with Eclipse latest release.

For reference:

**My Eclipse: Oxygen**

```
Version: Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2)
Build id: 20171218-0600
```

**My JRE/JDK: 1.8**

```
java version "1.8.0_152"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.152-b16, mixed mode)
```

**lombok 1.16.18**

Answer (score 3):

Follow the below steps,

1. Download lombok-jar from https://projectlombok.org/download
2. Go to the directory where your lombok-jar is downloaded and run below command,
   java -jar lombok-1.18.4.jar
3. Above command will open a window,
   [image]
4. Specify the eclipse app location and then click on install/update and proceed. The below screen will get display,
   [image]

Click on Quit installer.

5. Restart IDE. To check whether Lombok is installed or not. Got to -> About Eclipse -> [image]
6. You will see the installed lombok as below,
   [image]

Comment: Easy step-by-step guide.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, however, the original development was done with lombok 1.16.10 and I had installed 1.16.18.  When I downloaded and installed 1.16.10 everything worked.  I probably needed to do a few cleans and rebuilds to get it to work with .18, but if you're in a hurry, try that.

Answer (score 1):

Also had problems with lombok in eclipse oxygen.

My solution: returned from java version 8u144 to 8u141.

And I refer to lombok by adding this to my eclipse.ini:

-Xbootclasspath/c:/DEV/Tools/lombok-1.16.18/lombok.jar

-javaagent:/DEV/Tools/lombok-1.16.18/lombok.jar

Answer (score 1):

If restarting Eclipse doesn't help. You have to quit the application and make sure to kill all running java processes. That worked for me.

(Eclipse Oxygen 4.7.1a, OpenJDK 1.8.0_151-b12)

Answer (score 1):

Quite a few solutions, none solved my problem.

Eclipse Oxygen 3a April 2018 the installer works fine,

My issue was running eclipse on a DCEVM JRE. Pointing Eclipse to a non-modified JVM resolved this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am using STS.
After performing installation of lombok.jar shown above, need to perform following task.
STS -> Project -> Properties -> Java Compiler -> Annotation Processing -> Enable Annotation Processing.
See [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ide/issues/273)

Answer (score 1):

simplw way just download the **lombok.jar** open eclipse click with the right to **project** go to **build path** and **add an external jar** and import the jar restart the eclipse and everything is solve

Answer (score 0):

Had similiar issue but really don't remember what helped me.
Of course u can try restart Eclipse.
Make sure you mentioned correct Eclipse path in lombok installation.
That's the topic you can find other potential solutions: [Cannot make Project Lombok work on Eclipse (Helios)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418865/cannot-make-project-lombok-work-on-eclipse-helios/3425327#3425327)

Comment: I restarted eclipse multiple times and I installed lombok by double clicking on the jar, where I could chose the installation path. So that's not it. Thanks tho

Answer (score 0):

You can install lombok through command line very easily, `~/softwares/Eclipse.app/` path to your eclipse or sts app (this is on mac) but it will also work for different OS, and it will give you the successful output.

```
java -jar lombok.jar install ~/softwares/Eclipse.app/
```

Output:

```
Lombok installed to: /Users/temp/softwares/Eclipse.app
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried all this but it didn't work for me. Lombok libraries were still not adding into my classpath.

I was using the latest spring-boot version

2.1.9.RELEASE

when I reduced this to following version which worked for me

2.1.7.RELEASE

Answer (score 0):

If you have successfully installed Lombok and still facing the problem then right click on your project > maven > update project this should work.

Answer (score 0):

follow below steps to fix lombok issue in eclipse

1. First download the lombok jar ( add to pom , it will download . u can run from that location(from your maven repository location)
2. run jar from you maven repo location (java -jar lombok.jar)
3. select ur eclipse.exe location and install.
4. Add jar to maven/class path

After this you will able to see these below lines in eclipse.ini file

**-javaagent:locaton of lombok.jar

-Xbootclasspath/a:lombok.jar**

Note - if any line missing after follow these steps then add into your eclipse.ini and enjoy ur work.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue I have faced in eclipse. Installation was successful but I was seeing errors in my code. A simple maven update resolved this issue. In eclipse it is Alt+F5.

Answer (score 0):

Note**If you are doing all the avobe thing while eclipse is running then you will
not get the changes so just restart the eclise and you will fell the changes**

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse require specific java version

```
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=11
```

and Lombok is not java version agnostic, [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68117860/eclipse-2021-06-classformaterror-accessible-module-java-base-does-not-opens-j)

So you need to chose compatible versions, for example

- eclipse-2021-09-R
- lombok-1.18.20
- jdk-15.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Also before installing lombok check the java version. For latest releases of java version  you need to download the latest lombok.jar from the below link.
https://projectlombok.org/download

Answer (score 0):

[First step > Build Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3g0G.png)

Go to: Maven Dependencies > Build Path > Configure Build Path
Find Lombok dependency, click in its arrow then copy the full path from source attachment and paste into External annotations > restart your IDE and it'll work properly.

Answer (score -1):

Hello I solved that problem simply editing the lombok dependency in the pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.16.16</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

This version seems to work whit java 8.

Answer (score -1):

I solve it by deleting the project from Project Explorer, and import the project again.

Eclipse version: 2022-03 (4.23.0)

Lombok version: v1.18.24 (Envious Ferret)