# Project Lombok eclipse strangeness

Tags: java, eclipse, lombok

I have installed project lombok into eclipse. I see it installed when click about eclipse: "Lombok v1.18.4 "Envious Ferret" is installed. https://projectlombok.org/"

On the outline of class with the @Data annotation I see the getter and setters generated there. Also when I ctrl-click from a class which calls an autogenerated getter it takes me to the class correctly specifically to the @Data annotation. Maven also compiles everything just fine.

Sounds like everything is working great, except I have red underline errors everywhere over where a getter or setter is used. With errors like "The method xyz() is undefined for the type abcd" etc.

I've exited and re-opened eclipse and tried running a clean/build/update maven project. I checked that I have an entry for -javaagent and -Xbootclasspath/a in eclipse.ini

I'm not sure what else to try, but the errors are really annoying, as it'll be hard to know what's really an error and what's not. Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lombok problems with Eclipse Oxygen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45461777/lombok-problems-with-eclipse-oxygen)

Comment: have you tried installing through command and restarting it ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/52631933/9959152

Comment: I did see that and tried all of the solutions but still have the issue. I have tried through the command line too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing with this most of the day, I think there was something wrong with my eclipse (2019-09) installation or my workspace. I just reinstalled it with a new workspace and pulled in my same projects, then I reinstalled lombok the same way as before and all the errors are gone!