# Eclipse 2021-06: ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module

Tags: java, eclipse, lombok

Upgrading to the last Eclipse version, now I am getting the following error:

```
Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @5d01b0d8
```

I tried changing JDK under preferences with no luck.

Comment: If you are using Lombok, it's probably this issue: https://twitter.com/howlger/status/1407316561803763716 (changing the JDK under preferences, does not change the Java used to run Eclipse). Or a similar issue of a plugin you have installed.

Answer (score 44):

Thanks, @howlger it was Lombok plug-in when using JDK 16.
That tweet gave me the reasons: https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/2810

A workaround :

- Use Java 15 to start Eclipse or
- add `--illegal-access=warn` and `--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED` to your eclipse.ini
- or install a pre-built version (1.18.21)

In my situation I had to change eclipse.ini VM path:

```
-vm
C:\bin\jdk-15.0.2\bin
```

Comment: Confirming, JDK 17 also works fine.

Comment: Had the same issue with the subversion plugin and its SVN Connector. This fixed it instantly!

Comment: Seems some typo in the answer: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED works for me.

Comment: That issue had me struggling for a few days now. Thanks for your hints! setting the jvm to the jvm from sys (not the one coming with eclipse) did it.

Answer (score 3):

An easy way is to change the Java Version used to run Eclipse. There for you have to change the **eclipse.ini**.

1. Set the vm location at the **start** of the file to a prior Java 16 JDK e.g. JDK 14
2. Under MacOSX eclipse.ini is typically located in  /Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/
3. The reason is an incompatibility of the lombock plugin

---

This a working example of the **eclipse.ini** file:

```
-vm
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
-startup
../Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.6.200.v20210416-2027.jar
--launcher.library
../Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_1.2.200.v20210527-0259
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
-showsplash
org.eclipse.epp.package.common
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-javaagent:/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/lombok.jar
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=11
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-Dsun.java.command=Eclipse
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.graphics.Resource.reportNonDisposed=true
-Xms256m
-Xmx2048m
-Xdock:icon=../Resources/Eclipse.icns
-XstartOnFirstThread
```

Comment: There are some duplicate lines:  

`--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM`
`-XstartOnFirstThread`
`-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts`
`-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=11`

I suppose this is not on purpose?

Answer (score 3):

Latest version of lombok 1.18.22 has fixed this issue. Install this version of lombok into your eclipse. Then this issue will get resolved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thanks, this fixed it for me on eclipse 2021-12/4.22 with java 17

Comment: no luck here using lombok 1.18.24

Comment: I'm using 1.18.24 as well. As noted above, `--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED` did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I was using org.mockito.mockito-all as a test dependency in my project's pom. Moving to org.mockito.mockito-core as dependency resolved the issue.
Reflection is no longer supported in JDK 17, so mockito-all (using reflection) is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the SpringToolSuite4.ini as below:

```
-vm
C:\Users\my-id-here\softwares\openjdk-11.0.2\jdk-11.0.2\bin
```

and replacing the lombok.jar with the latest download. It worked!

Answer (score 1):

If you are starting your application from cmd (command prompt) and via the below command.

```
java -jar myapplication.jar
```

and getting this error. Then add the below in your command.

```
-Dsun.misc.URLClassPath.disableJarChecking=true --add-opens jdk.naming.rmi/com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/sun.security.action=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/sun.net=ALL-UNNAMED
```

Your command will look like this.

```
java -Dsun.misc.URLClassPath.disableJarChecking=true --add-opens jdk.naming.rmi/com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/sun.security.action=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/sun.net=ALL-UNNAMED -jar myapplication.jar
```

Now you will not get this error.