# java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-7

I am getting following error while running a test in my Project:

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @XXXXXX
```

I am using the green run arrow next to my test method to execute the test as specified [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-tests-in-maven.html).

Solution such as [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68117860/eclipse-2021-06-classformaterror-accessible-module-java-base-does-not-opens-j) might be helpful, but I am not sure how to pass a command line argument in this case `--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED` to be added while running the tests in a method specified above.?

Comment: Consider creating a `module-info.java` file and putting your code in a module. Search Google for **jpms** (Java Platform Module System). JPMS was introduced in Java 9 which was released in 2017.

Answer (score 3):

Please try the menu `Run | Edit Configurations...`, and click the `Modify options` drop-down, then click the checkbox menu `Add VM Options`, input:

`--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED`

This should fix this problem.

[image]