# Getting compilation error while using @Slf4j in Lombok in Eclipse

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle, lombok

Building the project using gradle in  eclipse  after Using @Slf4j annotation of lombok is throwing below error :

`Task :compileJava FAILED`

`error: cannot find symbol
        log.trace("logging now");
        ^
  symbol:   variable log`

But it is generating the .class file with the log variable correctly : `private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NetsuiteWebSecurityConfig.class);`

There is no problem with the @Data lombok annotation. It is generating getters/setters in .class file and also not throwing any error .

Note : i referred this [Cannot make Project Lombok work on Eclipse (Helios)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418865/cannot-make-project-lombok-work-on-eclipse-helios/3425327#3425327) for lombok installation . I can say lombok is working because it is generating the code in .class file . Not sure why it is failing while giving gradle build

Comment: Did you install the Eclipse plugin?

Comment: I guess there is no lombok eclipse plugin . But i installed lombok by downloading jar and running java -jar lombok.jar , it asked me eclipse directory . After installation i was able to see lombok mentioned in the about section of eclipse . I verified the eclipse.ini as well . Do eclipse have lombok plugin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed lombok correctly and set the annotations processor. But still nothing worked . What i have done is created a new folder at another place and cloned my git repository freshly there. To my surprise it worked . Dont know how , but the trick worked .