# Lombok @RequiredArgsConstructor not working, causing "the blank final field may not have been initialized" error during compilation in Eclipose

Tags: spring, eclipse, lombok

Eclipse throws error message that

> "the blank final field may not have been initialized"

even when i have the `@RequiredArgsConstructor` set.

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class DataWriter implements ApplicationRunner{

    private final AccountRepository accountRepo;

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {

    }

}
```

Compilation should not throw error because Lombok should have created the constructors automatically

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot make Project Lombok work on Eclipse (Helios)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418865/cannot-make-project-lombok-work-on-eclipse-helios)

Answer (score 8):

Eclipse doesn't support Lombok by default even after i have the lombok dependency in my pom.xml.

According to https://projectlombok.org/setup/eclipse, I'll need to run the lombok.jar by double-clicking it to have it look for the eclipse ide and install the plugin into eclipse. Eclipse restart is required.